# How can I load data on JSON instead of MySQL? (converting code)

Tags: java, mysql

My server loads data from MySQL which is unnecessarily. I want to load data from local JSON files instead. How I can do this ?

This is how data loaded from MySQL:

```java
 public static void loadShops() {
shops.clear();
Server.gameDb.executeAwait(new DatabaseStatement() {

    @Override
    public void execute(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
    PreparedStatement statement = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;

    try {
        statement = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM shops ORDER BY id");
        rs = statement.executeQuery();

        while (rs.next()) {
        int id = rs.getInt("id");
        String name = rs.getString("name");
        ShopType type = ShopType.get(rs.getString("type"));
        Currency currency = Currency.get(rs.getString("currency"));
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
        JsonObject object = (JsonObject) parser.parse(rs.getString("items"));
        ShopItem[] items = gson.fromJson(object.get("shop-items").getAsJsonArray(), ShopItem[].class);
        Shop shop = new Shop(name, id, type, currency, items);
        shops.put(id, shop);
        }
    } finally {
        DatabaseUtils.close(statement, rs);
    }
    }
});
}
```

How I can make this to load from Local .JSON files instead of MySQL ?

Thanks guys :D

EDIT: I tried to do something like this:

```java
@Override
public void load(JsonObject rs, Gson builder) {
    int id = rs.get("id").getAsInt();
    String name = rs.get("name").getAsString();
    ShopType type = ShopType.get(rs.get("type").getAsString());
    Currency currency = Currency.get(rs.get("currency").getAsString());
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
    JsonObject object = (JsonObject) parser.parse(rs.get("items").getAsString());
    ShopItem[] items = gson.fromJson(object.get("shop-items").getAsJsonArray(), ShopItem[].class);
    Shop shop = new Shop(name, id, type, currency, items);
    getShops().put(id, shop);
        System.out.println(rs.toString());
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? What issues are you facing? Please, come up with specific issue/question and [mcve], so we can help you. In common, read corresponding file -> POJO with the same structure as you json -> parse the json into this POJO.

Comment: Also, check this on how to convert pojo to/from json https://www.mkyong.com/java/jackson-2-convert-java-object-to-from-json/

Comment: I just edit the POST with what I tried to do, but I got this error: 

    `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: JsonObject
    at com.google.gson.JsonElement.getAsString(JsonElement.java:191)`